# Jumbotron background image isn't showing full-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Jumbotrons background image isn't quite making it full width.

Any idea why?

Live link: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

You can see the the width of the background image doesn't make it as far as the nav bar.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container special">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="h1extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h1 class="boldme">Aged 20-30 & frustrated with money?</h1> 
    <div class="greenpromobox">
    <div class="h2extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h2 class="boldme">Take our free <b class="jumpstarttext">Jumpstart Your Finances</b> class to<br /> quickly gain control over your finances</h2>


            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=299de51b4e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">


                   <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/hand-drawn-arrow.png" id="handarrow" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="arrow"><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email address" required autofocus>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_299de51b4e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Start Class Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->

</div>
</div>

 </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: url("../img/checking-finances-in-cafe-blurred.png");
background-size: cover;
color: white;
}

#handarrow {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: -5px;
    }

    html,body {height:100%;}
.special,.special .jumbotron 
{height:100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be the default margin or padding on the `html` and `body` tags. Try:

```
html, body {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

Not sure if that will work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, must be some Bootstrap defaults. Any idea why I've been downvoted?

Comment: I don't know... I think it is because people don't want to debug code, but honestly I don't care one way or the other. Plus one.

Comment: Haha no worries, I'm new here trying to figure it all out!

Comment: Me too. I only have 175 rep. Also a more or less amateur at web development, however I had this problem myself previously and found the answer online, so I jumped at the chance to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is bootstrap's `container` class, that takes up padding on both the left and right hand side. If you remove this class, the image will take up the full screen.

Or, you can use the `container-fluid` class

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.
>
> Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.
>
> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

I tested it out in Chrome's Developer tools, and that fixed it.

Comment: Made sense but didn't work for me, you may have refreshed after I had fixed using the solution above?

Answer (score 0):

it is due to you have added class container remove this class from first div it will resolve you issue.

`<div class="container special">` to `<div class="special">`